# Cloud firestore rules - how do I view a users rights by accessing different collections in the store?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a cloud firestore. In this store I have a collections of all admins. All data from the store can be read by anyone, but writes should be limited to the admins. If someone tries to write to a collection, e.g. latest-news, I want to see if the user that tries to write to the collection is an admin.
The idea I want is something like this:

```
 match /latest-news/{news-id} {
    allow read: if true;
    allow write: if <my-admin-collection>.map(auth => auth.uid).includes(request.auth.uid);
 }
```

How would I actually do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your collection of admins stores those admins by their UID, you can check for the existence of such a document from your rules with:

```
if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/admins/$(request.auth.uid));
```

The above allows the operation if a document with the current user's UID exists in the `/admins` collection.

Also see the documentation on [attribute-based and role-based access control](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#attribute-based_and_role-based_access).

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm! Do you know if there is any way to access fields in a document? E.g. if a value in the document determines whether or not the user who attempts to write is able to do so?

Comment: If you check the documentation link it does precisely that: it uses a field from the document to determine the role.

Comment: It was late when I read your reply lol. Thank you Frank!

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you define roles.
In firebase auth roles can be configured by [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).

Custom claims can be used in writing security rules like

```
match /latest-news/{news-id} {
   allow write: if request.auth.token.role == 'Admin';
}
```

Above security rule will only allow user from having role as 'Admin' to write to the collection.